# 1A - Theatre Square CodeForces

Tags: python, runtime

I am trying to answer the 1A-Theatre Square problem on CodeForces.
Its keeps telling me: "Runtime error on test 1"

Here is my code:

```
n= int(input())
m= int(input())
a= int(input())
n1=1
n2=1
while n>a*n1:
    n1=n1+1
    break
while m>a*n2:
    n2=n2+1
    break
print (n1*n2)
```

I am still a beginner, so I f you have any comment or advice, It would be appreciated and thank you for the time you took to read through my question.

Answer (score 0):

You will get time limit exceed, because the concept you are using has 2 loops that is time complexity of O(n). But the actual solution will have time complexity of O(1) i.e. it will not require any loops.

Hint:-
You will need, just a few if else based solution.

Answer (score 0):

n,m,a = map(int,input().split())

if n%a == 0: r1 = n//a else : r1 = (n//a)+1 if m%a == 0: r2 = m//a else : r2 = (m//a)+1

print(int(r1*r2))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).